# sound effects are not playing in my game

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna

I am developing a game for windows phone. The target version of game is 7.1 and 7.1 games and apps will be supported on wp8 devices.

Here is my code:

```
public SoundEffect l1;
public SoundEffectInstance level1sound;
l1 = contentManager.Load<SoundEffect>("sound/level1");
level1sound = l1.CreateInstance();
level1sound.IsLooped = true;
level1sound.Play();
```

Gaming sounds are working fine in simulator of 7.1 but when I deploy on wp8 device nothing works.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sound file properties should set to soundeffect type

Answer (score 0):

If you develop Silverlight game, you must call [`FrameworkDispatcher.Update()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.frameworkdispatcher.update.aspx) method in every frame to dispatch messages that are in the XNA Framework message queue

Comment: i am developing silverlight+ xna game and  FrameworkDispatcher.Update()  is not working for this.